# Google maps API V3 Passing Values to Javascript

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

While implementing Google Maps in android using **API V3(Javascript)** How do i pass values from activity to the javascript?
ie.. i want to pass the Latitude and Longitude values to Javascript inorder to display my current location on map..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few examples of this on Stack Overflow, e.g.

[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

[Calling javascript function from android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280197/calling-javascript-function-from-android-webview)

[Call javascript function in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023991/call-javascript-function-in-android-webview)

Comment: Create a function in your JavaScript called, say, showLocation which has 2 parameters (one for latitude, one for longitude). This function just needs to create a new point and add it to the map. Google's documentation for the Maps JavaScript SDK contains examples on how to do this (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/). Then, in your Java code, call your new "showLocation" JS function, the StackOverflow posts in my answer show you how to do this.