# Execute JavaScript function from Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, webviewchromium

I have been trying to call a JavaScript function called `showMenu();` from an Android WebView. However, I have tried what many articles on StackOverflow say about doing

```
webview.loadURL("javascript:showMenu()");
```

and it shows this in the console:

> I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: showMenu is not defined", source: https://url.com/index.php (1).

I am new at Android and I am pretty sure it is a simple fix, but I could not find it anywhere. How can I do this?

EDIT: JavaScript is enabled

Comment: This isn't java question

Comment: Make sure Javascript execution is enabled. or you can do so by `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`.  And make sure `showMenu()` is valid function, i suggest you try calling the same method on Google Chrome Insect window's console.

Comment: @SivakumarS I got that it is not defined. I currently have it set like `<script>function showMenu() { //Do something }</script>`

Comment: For Kotlin this might help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54386184/6247186

Answer (score 0):

I removed the function from the `<script>` tags, and put it in a `.js` file using `'use strict';` and worked :)